Cannot bulk delete/add rows in Excel from power automate - takes a lot of time
I have an excel file hosted on sharepoint and i work on it with power automate to delete rows and add new as per the business rules.
I loop throw the rows to delete and add rows (separate loops for both) and these loops have only the add/delete action. no other things happening. the concurrency of the loops is maximum i.e. 50.
The delete loop takes 1 hour to delete 2000 rows and the insert takes 40-45 minutes to insert 2000 rows. This is the count i expect everytime.
Any ideas on how can i reduce this time? maybe any APIs or something?
I tried graph APi calls and using child flows but did not work for me.

Look at using Office Scripts

Checkout the post from Reza. It uses graph API -https://youtu.be/pgcdYbpW1X0?si=jBCufK8JQuP0JET1

You could use Office Scripts like the one linked below to create, update, &/or delete at least 1000 rows per minute.
Update & Create: https://community.powerplatform.com/galleries/gallery-posts/?postid=70cda3d9-f80f-46b1-971a-7944e7e4ae0c
Delete: https://community.powerplatform.com/galleries/gallery-posts/?postid=ef2710b2-a2ca-4f56-aed9-c916aaf41f77
